Overprecision in Quartiles
For the descriptives of a certain study, I'm using SPSS to calculate medians and quartiles of variables in the total population and in pre-specified subgroups. During the process, I noticed that the first and third quartile would be specified in higher precision than possible.
For example, for the systolic tension measurements in the subgroup with tensions < 90 mmHg, only 14 measurements were available, namely '69, 71, 72, 73, 80, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 80, 87'. As you can see, the measurements have no decimal places, as it was not measured to that degree of precision, nor was it relevant.
When calculating the quartiles, SPSS returned the following results:

Q1: 72.75
Q2: 82.5
Q3: 87.0

While Q2 and Q3 are correct, Q1, to my knowledge, should be 73, not 72.75. Furthermore, even should there have been one measurement more, and the Q1 would lie in-between two numbers, for example 72 and 73, it would be 72.5, having only 1 decimal of precision, instead of 0.75, which has two.
What is SPSS doing that results in a 0.75, and are the results still trustworthy?
